# changing gerrit's canonical web url

Tags: url, web, gerrit, canonical-link

I have had an issue with setting up my gerrit server. The machine has Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server 64-bit installed on it. I am setting up git and gerrit as a way to manage source code and code review.
I require internal and external access to it. I setup a DNS that would work externally. However, during the initial setup, i left the canonicalWebUrl to its default value. It usually take's the machine's hostname (in this case it was vmserver). 
The issue I was running into is exactly as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702198/the-requested-url-openid-was-not-found-on-this-server, where after trying to sign in/register account with OPEN ID, it was saying url not found.

For some reason, it was changing the url in the address bar from the the DNS i setup to the CanonicalWebURL.

I tried to change the canonical web url in the gerrit.conf file found in etc of the gerrit site. After restarting the server, however, we were able to see the git project files present as they should be, but the account that was administrator seemed to no longer be registered and none of the projects were visible through gerrit.

I was wondering if there was a special procedure to changing the canonical web url in gerrit without disrupting access to a server?

any help or information on canonical urls would be much appreciated as i cannot find too much information on them.

edit:
looking deeper, i found some information that is way over my head regarding "submodules" 
i do not understand if this is what i am looking for or not.
https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/c/36190/

Answer (score 2):

The canonical web url must be set, and it sounds like you have done that correctly.

I suspect the issue you are seeing is caused by changing the canonical web url - some OpenID providers (Google being the big one) will return a different user ID based on the URL of the request.  This is a privacy thing and cannot be changed.  So previous users will now show up as new users and won't be in their old groups (Administrators group in this case).

If you don't have many users, it might be easiest to migrate them by hand.  You can modify the database to map the new user ID to the old user account.